# httpd rewriterule with another domain in parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, centos, vhosts

I do have an rewriterule looking like this

```
RewriteRule ^/test(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.com/cset_click.php?ex-aid=123&ex-cid=1234&ex-abt=123&ex-url=http://www.manageddomain.com/start/index.html?lang=de&wt_mc=de.bla.lba.bla [R=301,L]
```

wich is not working properly as it does simply redirect to www.manageddomain.com/start/index.html without the parameters and without redirect to somedomain in the first place.

So what im trying to achieve is that someone access www.manageddomain.com/test and gets redirected to www.someotherdomain....

Is there a trick ive been missing

Comment: I'd have thought you need to URL escape the characters in your query string for this to work